# auto populate list of questions if user select a category xyz

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, forms

I have a custom post type job with a category of different type. each type of job has it's own list of questions that I want user to answer. is there a plugin that i can use to achieve something like this? if no, I would like to know where to start from.

Example:

On the category I have two option (1- Builder and 2- Cleaner). If user select Builder I would like to ask the following questions:

1. Conversions & Extensions
   •   Kitchen/Rear Extension
   Single or double story extension?

   Single

   Double

   Not sure

•   Side Extension

Single or double story extension?

   Single

   Double

   Not sure

•   Loft Conversion

Do you own the building?

•   Yes

•   Purchase in progress

•   No

Do you have planning permission?

1. Yes
2. Waiting for Decision
3. Not required
4. No

And if user select Cleaner I would like to populate the following questions:

What do you need cleaning help with?

   House cleaning

   One-of cleaning

How many bedrooms and bathroom?

   1-2

   3-4

   5 or more

   Regular cleaning

How many bedrooms and bathroom?

   1-2

   3-4

   5 or more

Already Googled and found no answer hence I posting it here and hope one could help.

Thanks